# Export from Oracle SQL to CSV from Command

Tags: sql, oracle-sqldeveloper, sqlplus

I have a script that exports data (including CLOBs) from Oracle SQL to CSV via the command line. When I execute the script then view the data via Python, I get the correct number of columns for each row, along with the proper data. However, there are extra spaces in every cell. My approach:

**file.sql**:

```
spool "/home/username/file.csv";
SELECT /*csv*/ '"'||COLUMN_1||'"',
'"'||COLUMN_2||'"',
'"'||DBMS_LOB.substr(COLUMN_3,3000)||'"',
        ...
'"'||COLUMN_N||'"'
FROM TABLE; 
spool off;
```

**file.sh**:

```
export ORACLE_SID=MYSID
sqlplus / as sysdba <<EOF
conn myUser/myPass 
set heading off
set termout off 
set trimout off
set newpage none
set pages 0
set feedback off
set echo off
set verify off
set trimspool on
set sqlprompt "" 
set colsep ","
set linesize 32767      
@/home/username/file.sql
exit
EOF
```

When I attempt to trim spaces via concatenation, the entire thing falls apart (unequal column lengths, breaks where there should be none, etc.):

**Modified file.sql**:

```
spool "/home/username/file.csv";
SELECT /*csv*/ '"'||COLUMN_1||'"'||','
'"'||COLUMN_2||'"'||','
'"'||DBMS_LOB.substr(COLUMN_3,3000)||'"'||','
        ...
'"'||COLUMN_N||'"'
FROM TABLE; 
spool off;
```

What am I doing wrong here? I've also attempted a few other concatenation approaches, like using `||'","'||` instead, but that didn't seem to work either.

Comment: Have you checked for spaces in the data?  Try adding a TRIM() around the columns too.

Comment: No spaces in the data, and TRIM() doesn't appear to work. To be clear, my output looks like this: "VALUE" /s/s/s/s/s/s/s/s/s/s,"VALUE2"/s/s/s/s/s/s/s/s/s/s/s               ,                                    /s/s/s/s/s/s/s"VALUE3" /s/s/s/s/s/s/s/. Output within "" is fine.

Comment: Disregard my comment above and see the answer I posted instead.

Answer (score -1):

How about:

```
select col1 || ',' || col2 || ',' || col3 from tab1;
```

or

```
select '"' || col1 || '",' || '"' || col2 || '",' || '"' || finalcol || '"'  from tab1;
```

e.g.

```
SQL> select '"' || AD_ID || '",' || '"' || AD_SOURCETEXT || '",' || '"' || PRODUCT_ID || '"'  from pm.print_media where rownum < 4;

'"'||AD_ID||'",'||'"'||AD_SOURCETEXT||'",'||'"'||PRODUCT_ID||'"'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
"11001","TIGER2 Mousepad
Product Number: 2056   Price:  $8    Today's Sale Price

"12001","TIGER2 Mousepad
Product Number: 2056   Price:  $8    Today's Sale Price

"13001","TIGER2 3106 Keyboard
Product Number: 3106
* KB 101/EN keyboard is a sta
```

Answer (score -2):

Check this out: from this post: https://community.oracle.com/thread/2357292

Give each selected column an alias name.  It then worked for me.

```
SELECT /*csv*/ '"'||COLUMN_1||'"' COL1,
'"'||COLUMN_2||'"'                COL2,
'"'||DBMS_LOB.substr(COLUMN_3,3000)||'"' COL3,
        ...
'"'||COLUMN_N||'"' COLN
FROM TABLE;
```

EDIT: Added my example from running in Toad.

In Toad, I run this:

```
set heading off
set termout off 
set trimout off
set newpage none
set pages 0
set feedback off
set echo off
set verify off
set trimspool on
set trimout on
set tab off
set sqlprompt "" 
set colsep ","
set linesize 32767      

spool c:\temp\efs.txt;

SELECT '"'||'A'||'"',
'"'||'B'||'"',
'"'||'C'||'"'
FROM dual; 

spool off;
```

and get:

```
"A"          ,"B"          ,"C"
```

When I add the column aliases:

```
SELECT '"'||'A'||'"' a,
'"'||'B'||'"' b,
'"'||'C'||'"' c
FROM dual;
```

I get:

```
"A","B","C"
```

See this thread for another method and explanation (which is how we do it): https://community.oracle.com/thread/1081068

Comment: This doesn't appear to work for me either. I'll try ||'","|| with aliases next. To be honest, I can always trim the cells in Python - I just prefer to have a proper solution in SQL.

Comment: I get the same as you when selecting from dual for headers, but as soon as I select from TABLE it doesn't work for me. :-(

Comment: Well I'll be!  Same here.  ARGH  I would just follow that last link in my post and do it that way.  That's how we do it here, and at my previous job too.

Comment: I'm pulling my hair out over here! haha. I tried to select from dual first, followed by a select from table, using your approach, and that actually worked BUT now I only get back 20 rows out of a total of over 100k.

Comment: I think I'll just strip the darn cells in Python. cell.strip(). Done.